# OAuth2 and OpenID API to API communication

Tags: oauth-2.0, openid-connect

We have several microservices that communicate with each other and all these microservices use Oauth2 authorization to allow access to its API. The flow starts from the UI where we use the standard 'authorization_code' flow and finally get an access_token to invoke a specific API-1 service (Registered for client_id '123'). The UI then sends a request to the API-1 (client_id 123) and our API-1 now verifies the access token passed with auth server. Once it is valid this API now wants to communicate with another API (API-2) (Our internal microservice) which needs an access_token. We cannot re-use the same access_token as it is intended for a specific client. API-1 could use a token exchange to talk to API-2 but the developers of API-1 do not wan to do any token exchange. What are the options we have in this case?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The typical solution is to let API1 contact your token service, using its access token and exchange it using the token exchange standard, for a new access token to access API2.

See [OAuth 2.0 Token Exchange](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8693) and check with your token provider for details.

Comment: Thanks Tore but as I mentioned the developers of the API-1 microservice do not want to do any kind of token exchange. I was thinking of having an endpoint like an /introspect endpoint which will take a valid access token from any service and return a JWT with user information that could be passed on to other APIs. The JWT will be signed so that it is common to any client. So more like service to service communication would use a JWT if required instead of access_tokens.

Comment: You could use the client credentials flow between API1 and API2. and pass the user details as part of the API-operation parameters.

Comment: That would require API-1 to know the client_id and client_secret for API-2 correct and also of all other APIs it wants to communicate? This would be unacceptable

Comment: No, API1 has its own separate credentials and can ask for a token with a scope that points to API2.  using the clients credentials flow. The sender does not need to know the secret of the recevier.